# django debugger does not start in vscode

Tags: python, django, debugging

i'm trying to run a django debugger, but here's what happens.

from .forms import RegisterUserForm, LoginUserForm, IndexPageForm, OrderTicketForm
ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package

`launch.json`

```
"version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [

        {
            "name": "Django",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "stopOnEntry": false,
            "python": "${config.python.pythonPath}",
            "program": "${workspaceRoot}/manage.py",
            "args": [
                "runserver",
                "--no-color",
                "--noreload"
            ],
            "debugOptions": [
                "WaitOnAbnormalExit",
                "WaitOnNormalExit",
                "RedirectOutput",
                "DjangoDebugging"
            ]
        }
        
    ]
```

location venv and django project - `F:train/venv/`

[image: location venv and django project - F:train/venv/]

Comment: You need to fix your import error first, before you can run the debugger. Can you even run `python manage.py check` without that error? One common cause can be that you are missing the `__init__.py` file in your Python folders.

Comment: wait, do you have you Django project inside the venv folder? that would be wrong. I would suggest to put the venv folder on the top level of your project, right next to the folder that contains the `manage.py` file. But you do not want to put any project files inside the venv folder. It is manged by Python.

Comment: Thank you. I placed the venv above the level and everything worked